# Unable to write stream to a directory within a container due to "com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException"

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

I have two containers within which it has a similar folder structure. I'm using autoloader to read and write a stream of data coming as input from csv files. I can read the csv container as a stream but when I  try to write the stream,  I get an error as "com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: The specified resource name contains invalid characters."

`spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.stockseval.dfs.core.windows.net", "SAS") spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.token.provider.type.stockseval.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.sas.FixedSASTokenProvider") spark.conf.set("fs.azure.sas.fixed.token.stockseval.dfs.core.windows.net", dbutils.secrets.get(scope="stocksevalSAStoken", key="stocksevalSAStoken"))`

```
cloudFilesOption = {
    "cloudFiles.format": "csv",
    "cloudFiles.useNotifications": "true", # Use file notifications for efficient discovery
    "cloudFiles.includeExistingFiles": "true", # Process existing files in addition to new ones
    "cloudFiles.connectionString": dbutils.secrets.get(scope="stockseval-con-string", key="stockseval-con-string"),
    "cloudFiles.resourceGroup": "stocks",
    "cloudFiles.subscriptionId": dbutils.secrets.get(scope="subscription-id", key="subscription-id"),
    "cloudFiles.tenantId": dbutils.secrets.get(scope="tenant-id", key="tenant-id"),
    "cloudFiles.clientId": dbutils.secrets.get(scope="clientid", key="clientid"),
    "cloudFiles.clientSecret": dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "adls-db", key = "client-secret"),
    "cloudFiles.queueName": "stocksevalQ", # This queue will be created if it doesn't exist
    "cloudFiles.maxFilesPerTrigger": "100", # Number of files to process per micro-batch
    "cloudFiles.schemaLocation" : "abfss://financialdata-api@stockseval.dfs.core.windows.net/",
    "cloudFiles.schemaEvolutionMode"  : "addNewColumns"
}

landing_loc = "abfss://financialdata-api@stockseval.dfs.core.windows.net/balance-sheet-data-api/AnnualReports/"

df = spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles").options(**cloudFilesOption).option("Header" ,True).load(landing_loc)
```

```
bronze_layer = "abfss://financialdata-api-bronze@stockseval.dfs.core.windows.net/balance-sheet-data-api/AnnualReports/"
query1 = df.writeStream.format("delta").outputMode("append").trigger(once = True).queryName("Autoloader").option("checkpointLocation", "abfss://financialdata-api-bronze@stockseval.dfs.core.windows.net/").start(bronze_layer)
```

I have double-checked the names of containers and paths as well as recreated sas tokens in the storage account so that I can access multiple containers. I can even list files in the bronze location using db.utils.fs.ls ,and when the same path is given to write the stream it says an invalid character in the resource. Not sure what to do here honestly. Any help would appreciated as this is my first Azure project.

[image: I can read the stream]

Answer (score 1):

The error you getting is because of

```
"cloudFiles.queueName": "stocksevalQ"
```

Here, you should not give capital letters for queue name.

I've got the same error when tried your code.

[image]

If you try to create queue with this name you will get error as you can see below.

[image]

So try give queue name which match this conditions.
I gave `stockseval` and executed successfully.

And if you can see data in bronze layer.

[image]

And

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, yes that was indeed the error.  The error has been fixed.However, I'm facing another issue. I have 5 CSV files sitting in the landing zone and after I read the stream, when i try to write it in the bronze layer, I can see a folder being created but the cell output says "Command submitted to compute for execution" and Stream initializing, and nothing happened except for a few folders being created. It's been the same for 10 mins or more. I have the exact same code as yours

Comment: Start stream with `start().awaitTermination()`

Comment: Oh right thank you Jayshankar. Cheers